# Deserialize XML HTTP Response with C#

Tags: c#, xml, http, xml-deserialization

I am trying to write a serialization class, so that it would deserialize the http response from a camera device, however I and getting hung up on excluding the xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation tag. The deserialization fails with "xsi" is an undeclared prefix error message.

XML Http Response:

```
<root xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='http://www.example.com/vapix/http_cgi/recording/stop1.xsd'><stop recordingid='20161125_121817_831B_ACCC8E627419' result='OK'/></root>
```

C# code:

```
try
{
  StopRecord ListOfStops = null;
  XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(StopRecord));
  using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(httpResponse)))
  {
   ListOfStops = deserializer.Deserialize(reader) as StopRecord ;
  }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
}
```

C# Serialization Class:

```
public class StopRecord
{
   [Serializable()]
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("root")]
   public class Root
   {
     public class stop
     {
       public stop(){}
       [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("recordingid")]
       public string recordingid {get;set;}

       [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("result")]
       public string result {get;set;}
     }
   }
}
```

Updated: Changed XmlElements to XmlAttributes. The problem with xsi still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap this xml response with a new root element where the *xsi* namespace is defined:

```
<wrapper xmlns:xsi='http://www.example.com'>
    <!-- original response goes here -->
    <root xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='http://www.example.com/vapix/http_cgi/recording/stop1.xsd'>
        <stop recordingid='20161125_121817_831B_ACCC8E627419' result='OK'/>
    </root>
</wrapper>
```

You also need to change your classes to add the Wrapper class - [working example on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GPz4bY):

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("wrapper")]
public class StopRecord
{
    [XmlElement("root")]
    public Root Root { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    [XmlElement("stop")]
    public Stop stop { get; set; }
}

public class Stop
{
    [XmlAttribute("recordingid")]
    public string recordingid { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("result")]
    public string result { get; set; }
}
```

There is no need to deserialize *noNamspaceSchemaLocation* attritbute.

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution took care of the problem. Can you explain what the wrapper is actually doing?

Comment: The wrapper element is the new root and defines xsi namespace (xmlns:xsi='http://www.example.com') for the whole document so it is recognized by deserializer and you can use the attribute from this namespace (xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation).

Answer (score 0):

The [xsi:noNamspaceSchemaLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256139(v=vs.110).aspx) attritbute shouldn't be deserialized as it is for the structure of the XML Document.

Since recordingid and result are attributes, not elements, they need to be serialized as XmlAttribute instead of XmlElement.

```
public class StopRecord
{
    [Serializable()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("root")]
    public class Root
    {
        public class stop
        {
            public stop(){}

            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("recordingid")]
            public string recordingid {get;set;}

            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("result")]
            public string result {get;set;}
        }
    }
}
```